# How can i get shipping address for all open magento orders?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.3

I am using ancient Magento 1.3.2.4 and trying to get shipping address for all the orders with processing status, I am using below code but it doesn't give me any shipping id or any address data.

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$app = Mage::app();

//Getting Processing Order IDs
$orderIDs = array();
$salesCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING));

foreach($salesCollection as $order)
{
    print_r($order);
}
```

I have also tried

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($id);
```

but no luck

Output:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_order
    [_eventObject:protected] => order
    [_addresses:protected] => 
    [_items:protected] => 
    [_payments:protected] => 
    [_statusHistory:protected] => 
    [_invoices:protected] => 
    [_tracks:protected] => 
    [_shipments:protected] => 
    [_creditmemos:protected] => 
    [_relatedObjects:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_orderCurrency:protected] => 
    [_baseCurrency:protected] => 
    [_actionFlag:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_resourceName:protected] => sales/order
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/order_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 9693
            [entity_type_id] => 11
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [increment_id] => 200015066
            [parent_id] => 0
            [store_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 2015-09-03 18:24:37
            [updated_at] => 2015-09-03 18:24:37
            [is_active] => 1
            [customer_id] => 
            [tax_amount] => 1.1600
            [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [subtotal] => 5.8300
            [grand_total] => 6.9900
            [total_paid] => 6.9900
            [total_refunded] => 0.0000
            [total_qty_ordered] => 0.0000
            [total_canceled] => 0.0000
            [total_invoiced] => 6.9900
            [total_online_refunded] => 0.0000
            [total_offline_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_amount] => 1.1600
            [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal] => 5.8300
            [base_grand_total] => 6.9900
            [base_total_paid] => 6.9900
            [base_total_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_total_qty_ordered] => 0.0000
            [base_total_canceled] => 0.0000
            [base_total_invoiced] => 6.9900
            [base_total_online_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_total_offline_refunded] => 0.0000
            [subtotal_refunded] => 
            [subtotal_canceled] => 
            [discount_refunded] => 
            [discount_canceled] => 
            [discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [tax_refunded] => 
            [tax_canceled] => 
            [shipping_refunded] => 
            [shipping_canceled] => 
            [base_subtotal_refunded] => 
            [base_subtotal_canceled] => 
            [base_discount_refunded] => 
            [base_discount_canceled] => 
            [base_discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_refunded] => 
            [base_tax_canceled] => 
            [base_shipping_refunded] => 
            [base_shipping_canceled] => 
            [subtotal_invoiced] => 5.8300
            [tax_invoiced] => 1.1600
            [shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_invoiced] => 5.8300
            [base_tax_invoiced] => 1.1600
            [base_shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_refunded] => 
            [base_shipping_tax_refunded] => 
            [status] => processing
        )

    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 9693
            [entity_type_id] => 11
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [increment_id] => 200015066
            [parent_id] => 0
            [store_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 2015-09-03 18:24:37
            [updated_at] => 2015-09-03 18:24:37
            [is_active] => 1
            [customer_id] => 
            [tax_amount] => 1.1600
            [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [subtotal] => 5.8300
            [grand_total] => 6.9900
            [total_paid] => 6.9900
            [total_refunded] => 0.0000
            [total_qty_ordered] => 0.0000
            [total_canceled] => 0.0000
            [total_invoiced] => 6.9900
            [total_online_refunded] => 0.0000
            [total_offline_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_amount] => 1.1600
            [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal] => 5.8300
            [base_grand_total] => 6.9900
            [base_total_paid] => 6.9900
            [base_total_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_total_qty_ordered] => 0.0000
            [base_total_canceled] => 0.0000
            [base_total_invoiced] => 6.9900
            [base_total_online_refunded] => 0.0000
            [base_total_offline_refunded] => 0.0000
            [subtotal_refunded] => 
            [subtotal_canceled] => 
            [discount_refunded] => 
            [discount_canceled] => 
            [discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [tax_refunded] => 
            [tax_canceled] => 
            [shipping_refunded] => 
            [shipping_canceled] => 
            [base_subtotal_refunded] => 
            [base_subtotal_canceled] => 
            [base_discount_refunded] => 
            [base_discount_canceled] => 
            [base_discount_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_refunded] => 
            [base_tax_canceled] => 
            [base_shipping_refunded] => 
            [base_shipping_canceled] => 
            [subtotal_invoiced] => 5.8300
            [tax_invoiced] => 1.1600
            [shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_invoiced] => 5.8300
            [base_tax_invoiced] => 1.1600
            [base_shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_refunded] => 
            [base_shipping_tax_refunded] => 
            [status] => processing
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked so I dared to look into magento's DB tables and the SQL below works

```
SELECT
    a.address_type,
    a.firstname,
    a.middlename,
    a.lastname,
    a.suffix,
    a.street,
    a.city,
    a.region,
    a.postcode,
    a.country_id
FROM
    sales_flat_quote_address AS a,
    sales_order_varchar AS v,
    sales_order_int AS o
WHERE
    v.attribute_id = 97
        AND v.value = 'processing'
        AND o.entity_id = v.entity_id
        AND o.attribute_id = 109
        AND o.value = a.quote_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$app = Mage::app();

//Getting Processing Order IDs
$orderIDs = array();
$salesCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);

foreach($salesCollection as $order)
{
    print_r($order);
}
```

Comment: @Keyur: just do filter with 'status' not the 'state'